# Apache Beam Find Top N elements Python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My requirement is to read from a BQ table, do some processing, select the Top N rows on the "score" column and write it to the BQ Table and also publish the rows as a PubSub message.

I made a sample below to create a PCollection and select top 5 rows from this PCollection based on the value of "score".

```
import apache_beam as beam

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    elements = (
      p
        | beam.Create([{"name": "Bob", "score": 5}, 
                       {"name":"Adam", "score": 5},
                       {"name":"John", "score": 2},
                       {"name":"Jose", "score": 1},
                       {"name":"Tim", "score": 1},
                       {"name":"Bryan", "score": 1},
                       {"name":"Kim", "score":1}])
        | "Filter Top 5 scores" >> beam.combiners.Top.Of(5, key=lambda t: t['score']) 
        | "Print" >> beam.Map(print)
        )
   # Write to BQ
   # Publish to PubSub
```

This returns a list instead of a PCollection. Hence I'm unable to write it back to BQ table nor publish to PubSub in this format.

What is the best way to select the top N elements but keep them as a PCollection?

In my real use case I might have around 2 million rows and I need to select 800k records from it based on a column.
Also in one of the Apache Beam summit videos I remember hearing that the Top function will keep the results in one worker node instead of keeping it across. So thats why i assume it is a list. What would be the maximum number of the rows before which it could break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue, you can add a `FlatMap` transformation after the `Top` operator :

```
def test_pipeline(self):
    with TestPipeline() as p:
        elements = (
                p
                | beam.Create([{"name": "Bob", "score": 5},
                               {"name": "Adam", "score": 5},
                               {"name": "John", "score": 2},
                               {"name": "Jose", "score": 1},
                               {"name": "Tim", "score": 1},
                               {"name": "Bryan", "score": 1},
                               {"name": "Kim", "score": 1}])
                | "Filter Top 5 scores" >> beam.combiners.Top.Of(5, key=lambda t: t['score'])
                | "Flatten" >> beam.FlatMap(lambda e: e)
                | "Print" >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

In this case the result is a `PCollection` of `Dict` instead of a `PCollection` of `List[Dict]`.

You have to be carreful with high volume because the `beam.combiners.Top.Of` operation is done only in one worker.

You can also optimize and make your `Dataflow` job more powerful with [Dataflow Prime](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/enable-dataflow-prime) if needed (Right Fitting, Vertical Autoscaling inside a Worker...).